# Find two numbers $a,b$ such that $a^a=b^b$

Tags: exponentiation

Playing around on Desmos with the equation $y=x^x$, I noticed that the function, for numbers $0<x<1$, has two $x$ values for every $y$ value. For instance, $\frac12^{\frac12}=\frac14^{\frac14}$, which we can rewrite as $\sqrt[2]\frac12=\sqrt[4]\frac14$.

What I'm trying to find is: Given some number $a$ such that $0<a<1$, find $b$ such that $\sqrt[a]\frac1a=\sqrt[b]\frac1b$.

Is there a general formula for this? I've tried using Newton's Method, but that just approximates the result; it doesn't give an exact answer.

<sub>I'm struggling with tagging this question properly, so I'd appreciate some help with that as well.</sub>

Comment: You could try plotting $f(x,y) = (x^x-y^y)^2$ as a surface above $\mathbb{R}^2$. This would be minimum at solutions to your equation.

Comment: @George Where does that function come from? How exactly does that help?

Comment: @Oscar Granted that your answer uses parametrics, the question doesn't. I don't feel that that tag is warranted here.

Comment: Ok, couldn't think of anything better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $t=a/b$ be a positive number other than $1$.  Then

$(bt)^{bt}=b^b$

$(bt)^t=b$

$bt=b^{1/t}$

$t=b^{(1-t)/t}$

$\color{blue}{b=t^{t/(1-t)}}$

From this we then get

$\color{blue}{a=bt=t^{1/(1-t)}}$

For instance, if $t=2$ then $b=2^{2/(1-2)}=1/4, a=2^{1/(1-2)}=1/2$.

Comment: Your final equality holds for all positive $t\ne1$, where you get a divide-by-zero error in the exponent, where for every solution $a,b$ given some $t>1$, there's an equivalent solution $b,a$ for every $0<t<1$. What's really interesting, though, is that your equality holds even for negative $t$, if you avoid picking $t$ such that you end up with an imaginary answer, yielding a negative $a$ and positive $b$ (with the same feature that for every solution $a,b$ for $t<-1$, there's an equivalent solution $b,a$ for every $-1<t<0$). Thank you so much for this; you've given me much to work with here.

Comment: Try putting $t=-1$.  You get no real solutions, but you do get an elegant result.

Comment: $a=i, b=\frac1i$? That’s just making my head hurt trying to figure out how to deal with that. :)

Comment: $i^i=(-i)^{(-i)}$!

Answer (score -1):

Let $f(x)=x^x$
$$\ln(f(x))=x\ln x$$
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=(1+\ln x)$$
$$f'(x)=f(x)\ln(ex)$$
$$\text{For }0<ex<1,f'(x)\lt0$$
$$\text{For }ex>1,f'(x)\gt 0 $$
$$\text{Hence, if }a\in\left(0,\frac1e\right),b>\frac1e$$

Comment: How does this help? This doesn't give you an actual pairing of numbers, just what range they're in.

Comment: This says for every a $\in {(0,\frac{1}{e})}$ there exist exactly one b$\gt 1$ that will satisfy the equation.

Comment: That's fine, but it doesn't say that for a specific $a$ how to find that $b$ which will satisfy the equation.

Comment: For that let b=$a^x$ now you end up with equation $$xa^x-a=0$$ now take different a and x you will get b.

Comment: Great, but that's not what it says in your answer.

Comment: In my answer I want to say that if you take any a then since $x^x$ is many- one function we can always find b  corresponding to that a and there exist unique such b. Graphically it can be seen also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101731/discussion-between-donielf-and-mathsdiscussion-com).